# Schedule a Jenkins build at 2 AM everyday, except for Sunday. On Sundays it should trigger at 10 AM

Tags: jenkins

I need to schedule my Jenkins build at 2 AM everyday, except for Sunday. On Sunday, it should build at 10 AM.

For the first part, I have used H 2 * * *. Now I need to know what should I use along with this so that the jobs builds at 10 AM only on Sundays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need two separate CRON expressions for this.

Answer (score 0):

So what I understood, you would like to setup multiple cron entries.
First entry is for Monday to Saturday and second entry is only for Sunday.

Using the Using the job-dsl syntax, you can do it like below way:

```
triggers {
cron('example entry 1 \n example entry 2')}
```

Please refer this>>https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob-triggers-cron

As per the above link,use a single trigger string with entries separated by \n to configure multi line entry.

Cron support string parameter.

```
cron('example entry 1' + '\n example entry 2' + '\n example entry 3 *')
```

Thanks.